# How to access stateful session bean through remote interface proxy?

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-3.0, openejb

I have a testcase which makes use of [OpenEjb](http://openejb.apache.org)'s @LocalClient annotation (embedded container) and injects EJBs using the @EJB annotation:

```
@LocalClient
public class MyTestCase {

    @EJB
    private BoxDao boxDao;
    
    ...   
    
}
```

BoxDao is a remote EJB interface. Now, for testing, I need to access some internal state of BoxDao's implementation BoxDaoBean, which is a stateful session bean. I created a protected method in BoxDaoBean, which exposes the needed internal state, but I found not yet a way to access it in my test case, since the injected BoxDao is a remote interface proxy (an cannot be cast to BoxDaoBean).

Is there a way to access the stateful session bean behind the remote interface BoxDao in the test case? Would not matter if solution is [OpenEjb](http://openejb.apache.org) specific.

**Update:** We can't use EJB 3.1 specific solutions unfortunately, as we have several EJB 3.0 projects running. Using Proxy.getInvocationHandler(boxDao), I can get access to the OpenEjb container, via StatefulEjbObjectHandler. Is it possible to access the stateful bean this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try having `BoxDaoBean` also expose an `@LocalBean` interface.  A single EJB can expose a near unlimited number of views from `@WebService`, `@Local`, `@Remote`, JAX-RS and more.

Just update your bean like so:

```
@Stateful
@LocalBean
public class BoxDaoBean implements BoxDao {
   //...
}
```

Then add another field to your test:

```
@LocalClient
public class MyTestCase {

    @EJB
    private BoxDao boxDao;

    @EJB
    private BoxDaoBean boxDaoBean;

    ...   

}
```

Comment: I tried this but, at least regarding GlassFish, you have to use vendor specific JNDI names to get it work. Something we cannot do in our project. :(  See [here](http://expertdevelopers.blogspot.de/2010/05/experimenting-ejb3-part-ii.html)

Comment: Nothing in that blog post is up-to-date.  In Java EE 6 we took the embedded EJB Container concept of OpenEJB and incorporated it into the EJB 3.1 spec as the `javax.ejb.embedded.EJBContainer` API.  We then standardized the EJB JNDI names using the new `java:global` and `java:app` namespaces.  Here's an [example test case that does lookup](http://openejb.apache.org/examples-trunk/simple-stateless/README.html).  Unfortunately test case injection did not make it into the EJB 3.1 standard.  OpenEJB still supports it via `EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(p).getContext().bind("inject", this)`.

Comment: Thanks for the update David, I will bring this to the team. As an alternative, (e.g. for our EJB 3.0 projects), do you think there is a way to get the stateful bean instance via the proxy? I saw that by calling Proxy.getInvocationHandler(boxDao), I get access to the OpenEjb container, via StatefulEjbObjectHandler. Starting there, it should be possible to get through to the inctance, right?

Comment: That won't get you the instance.  Closest you can get with that is the Container, but the instance itself is hidden inside container.  You could maybe use the [alt-dd](http://openejb.apache.org/examples-trunk/alternate-descriptors/) support to add an extra Local interface for testing purposes.

Comment: David, thanks alot for that hint. Alternate descriptors work like a charm!